# looking for a Pixenate alternative - simple self-hosted online image editor

Tags: html, self-hosted, image-editor

I am searching for a (if possible customizable) self-hosted online image editor

The aim: users upload images to our site and, before finalizing the upload, should get the chance to edit the image. Nothing too sophisticated; just basic operations like crop, resize, flip/90°rotate, adjust lighting and contrast, and - if possible - a simple drawing function for basic shapes (circle, rectangle, filled or not).

I used to add Pixenate to my projects, which has been discontinued a couple of years back. Pxn8 was a perl script using ImageMagick, both causing some security issues; I would be happy with a pure HTML5/Canvas solution.

Google was not very helpful; Whatever set of search terms I chose, I get flooded with photo management or desktop solutions like Gimp, Paint etc.

[miniPaint](https://github.com/viliusle/miniPaint) seems to have all I need - except for sending the image to the server.